# Real and float number decimal length and accuracy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand that [**float and real are**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly.

However, in the following example:

**Q1:** Why *'float(**24**)'* (ie; real) gives *more decimals* than *'float(**53**)'* yet less accurate?

**Q2:** How do I store *@s in a number field* as it is without rounding?

```
declare @s varchar(50) = '34.770438199999944'
select convert(float(24), @s) real_, convert(float(53), @s) float_
```

[**Results**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2856) (brackets are to make the diff more clear)

```
|             real_ |       float_ |
------------------------------------
| 34.77043(9147949) | 34.77043(82) |
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1. it's only a display problem, for other numbers it might be different. It will round where it will fit better (it will be closer to the real approximation of the number). Less precision because it has less data to store the number in.

Q2. In mssql (as the tag states sql-server) you can make a decimal, and you will store the number without precision loss. But the number you can store is limited.

Comment: Can you explain `Less precision because it has less data to store the number in`? is it about float or real?

Comment: well .. every number either floating point or not is represented on a number of bits. For example 1 byte = 8 bits. It can hold numbers from 0 to 255 (2^8 numbers). If you go to an 2 byte number you will have 2^16 and so on. With floating points the reasoning is similar, but there the number is not stored as it is but as 2 numbers in fact: significant digits and exponent. With this 2 you can approximate a very big range of numbers. Now float and real are represented with different number of bytes. Float which has more byte to store the 2 numbers in it can hold data much more accurately.